# How do i fix createPortal in NextJS when using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm using Nextjs + Typescript to make a toy project
and I'm having a problem when using createPortal to create a Modal.
Clicking the button does nothing.
This is probably because the value of ref.current is null.
why doesn't it work?
Plz help me.

[image]

[image]

HOC/Portal.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

interface Props {
  children: any;
}
const Portal: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.querySelector("overlay-root");
    setMounted(true);
    return () => setMounted(false);
  }, []);

  console.log(ref.current, "ref.current?");
  console.log(mounted, "mounted");

  return (mounted && ref.current) ? createPortal(children, ref.current!) : null;
};

export default Portal;
```

src/Components/layout/Header.tsx

```
...
 {isLoginModal && (
            <Portal>
              <Login
                onChangeLoginModal={onChangeLoginModal}
                onChangeLoginState={onChangeLoginState}
                isLoginState={isLoginState}
                isLoginModal
              />
            </Portal>
          )}
...
```

pages/_documents.tsx

```
 ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
          ></meta>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dongle&family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          {/* here */}
          <div id="overlay-root"></div>
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

As a test, I tried the following simple case.
but the result was the same.

src/Components/layout/Header.tsx

```
...
 <Portal>
         <div>Testing<div>
 </Portal>
 {isLoginModal && (
              <Login
                onChangeLoginModal={onChangeLoginModal}
                onChangeLoginState={onChangeLoginState}
                isLoginState={isLoginState}
                isLoginModal
              />
          )}
...
```

Comment: have you tried using useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect ?

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAkram thank you for message.
but the result was same.
The value of ref.current was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface Props extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement> {
  /**
   * the html tag you want to create.
   * @default "section"
   */
  section: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
  id:string;
  className: string;
}
const Portal:React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const { section, id,className, children, ...rest } = props;
    const el = document.createElement(section);
    const wrapper:React.RefObject<HTMLElement>  = useRef(el);

    useEffect(() => {
        const current = wrapper.current as HTMLElement;
if(!current) return;
        
            current.setAttribute("id", id);
            current.setAttribute("class", className);

            Object.keys(rest).forEach(attribute=>{
                const val: keyof typeof rest = rest[(attribute as keyof typeof rest)];
                current.setAttribute(attribute, val);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(current);
        

        return () => {
                document.body.removeChild(current);
        };
    }, [wrapper,id, className]);

    if (!wrapper.current) {
        return <>{null}</>;
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, wrapper.current);
};

Portal.defaultProps = {
  section:"section"
}

export default Portal;
```

Comment: thank you for answer. 
I tyied it. fortunately it works. 
so I can see additional div-element in the console. 
but it doesn't show up in the Browser.

Comment: Add am if inside the hook, checkthe code

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for Ernesto.
Your answer solved it.
Based on your comments, I changed it to the following

```
const Portal: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  const wrapper: React.RefObject<HTMLElement> = useRef(el);

  useEffect(() => {
    const current = wrapper.current as HTMLElement;
    current.setAttribute("id", "overlay");
    document.body.appendChild(current);
    
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(current);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!wrapper.current) {
    return <>{null}</>;
  }
  return createPortal(children, wrapper.current);
};

export default Portal;
```

[image]